# Why my mutexes doesn't grant exclusive access?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

My C program has three threads `A`, `B`, and `C` that share some buffers. Each buffer is protected by a mutex, and each thread has to lock the mutex before writing/reading a buffer.

`A` writes the buffers, and `B` and `C` reads the buffers. The main function creates `A`, waits until it locks the first buffer with `pthread_mutex_lock()`, and then creates `B` and `C`, so that the buffers are always written before being read.

- main.c

```c
#define mutex_lock(mutex, buff_num)        log("wait on buff[%d]\n", buff_num);  \
                                           printf("pthread_mutex_lock returns %d\n", pthread_mutex_lock(mutex));   \
                                           log("buff[%d] locked\n", buff_num)
    
#define mutex_unlock(mutex, buff_num)      log("releasing buff[%d]\n", buff_num); \
                                           pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);           \
                                           log("buff[%d] released\n", buff_num)

...
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t  lock;
    char             data[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
} buff_t;

uint8_t A_thread_ready = 0;
buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];
...

int main()
{
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_BUFF; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&buff[i].lock, NULL) != 0)
        {
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
    ...
    status = pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, &A_thread, NULL);
    if ( 0 == status)
    {
        break;
    }

    do
    {
        nanosleep(&t1, &t2);
    } while (0 == A_thread_ready);

    status = pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, &B_thread, NULL);
    if ( 0 == status)
    {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

- a.c

```c
...

extern uint8_t A_thread_ready;
extern buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];

...

void* A_thread(void* arg)
{
    uint8_t write_buff = 0;
    ...
    buff_p = &(buff[write_buff]);
    mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
    A_thread_ready = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        ...
        mutex_unlock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
        write_buff++;
        write_buff %= NUM_BUFF;
        buff_p = &(buff[write_buff]);
        mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, write_buff);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

- b.c

```c
...

extern buff_t buff[NUM_BUFF];

...

void* B_thread(void* arg)
{
    uint8_t read_buff = 0;
    ...
    buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);
    mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);

    while(1)
    {
        ...
        mutex_unlock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
        read_buff++;
        read_buff %= NUM_BUFF;
        buff_p = &(buff[read_buff]);
        mutex_lock(&buff_p->lock, read_buff);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When a thread was locking a mutex, the three logs always appeared in three successive lines: the log waiting on the mutex before the `printf()` in the macro, `pthread_mutex_lock()` returned 0 (denoting a success), and the log showing buffer locked right after the `printf()`.

When running the program, however, from the printed logs, it seems that accessing to a buffer is not exclusive: after `A` locked a buffer, `B` was able to lock this same buffer. It then did something, and released the buffer. After some time `A` released this buffer.  What else should I check to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: This needs a [mcve] that people can compile, run, and test; not a bunch of snippets with ... in between.

Comment: You have a data race on `A_thread_ready`.  It either needs to be `_Atomic`, or it needs a mutex of its own to protect it.  I don't know if that's related to your issue, but strictly speaking, it makes the entire program have undefined behavior.

Comment: Moreover, testing `A_thread_ready` does not provide assurance that `A_thread` has actually taken its lock; a non-atomic variable cannot provide synchronization.

Comment: The phrase _it seems that accessing to a buffer is not excessive_ doesn't mean anything to me.  Did you mean _access to a buffer is not exclusive_?  Also, can you please cut and paste the portion of the log messages that you find unexpected?  As your code is currently written, you may very well see `buff[1] locked` (by A) followed by `buff[1] released` (by B). Even though the locking is correct because `wait on buff` and `buff[%d] released` are logged **outside** the mutex-guarded code.  You may just have some personal incredulity and be drawing the wrong conclusions from your observations.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, a compilable code will be more helpful. I need to think about how to tailor the original one that still exhibit the problem while I'm not aware when it comes from.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll explain the issue with `A_thread_ready` in a separate answer due to the character limitation in a comment.

Comment: @Support Ukraine @Wyck Yes, it should be `exclusive` instead of `excessive`. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, I can paste the logs on Monday as the computer is connected to a private network that I can't access from outside. But they did appear as you said. What are the better/correct ways to show if a mutex has been locked beside using these "sequenced" logs?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `if ( 0 == status)
    {
        break;
    }` The `break` isn't inside a loop so it won't compile.

Comment: Quote: "... it seems that accessing to a buffer is not exclusive" I don't believe that. I think you are drawing wrong conclusions. Except for the first time (index 0), you have no control at all to ensure that thread A has actually written to a buffer before B starts reading. Further, you have nothing to control that B has read a buffer before A overwrites it. So "strange" things can happe. For instance A write index 0, then B reads index 0, index 1, index 2, then A write index 1, then B reads index 3 and so on. In general the buffer access is out of control.

Comment: (continued) For several reasons (e.g. nanosleep) thread A will write several buffers before thread B starts. Thread A could write many more than just NUM_BUFF. So again it's out of control. Also the print/log has no thread name so it's probably impossible to see what is going on...

Comment: @SupportUkraine OK I think I'm aware where I might be wrong. What I expected is that `A` always locks a buffer before `B` locks the same buffer, it should always be ahead. In fact the operations that `A` unlocks buffer `n`, increases the pointer, locks buffer `n+1` is not atomic. So if `A` unlocks `n` and then is suspended before locking buffer `n+1`, chances are `B` will lock `n+1` and read invalid data. I will set a flag in the buffer data struct so that `B` unlocks the buffer if it hasn't been written.

Comment: @SupportUkraine But this might be a different problem in my code. I printed the data read out of the buffer in `B`, which should be non-0s. However I saw it printed non-0s (few hundred bytes) followed by all 0s. It seems `A` had written a portion of the buffer before `B` took over. I'll double check the logs and report back tomorrow. The `if {break;}` is inside a `while(1)` loop that retries until the thread is created.

Comment: @NateEldredge OK. I'll change `A_thread_ready` to `_Atomic` and see how that changes the result.

Comment: @fiedel If you have a `while(1)` somewhere in `main` it should be part of the posted code. As it is now, it's very confusing. Actually, you should post code that we can copy, compile and test directly.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Sorry for the confusion. I'll compose and post compilable code later. Should it be a new post? The comment is limited to 600 characters, and I guess I shouldn't edit the original code in this question.

Comment: Looked at the logs today. This "dual-access" to a same buffer happened to buffer `2` as `A` locked this buffer, then `B` locked and read from it before `A` unlocked this buffer. Printing the data from the buffers was disabled in this run, so I can't tell what happened exactly. The devices connected to run the program was removed and I can't test for now. Will update when they are available again.

Comment: Please **do** edit the code into a reproducible example.  What's currently there is not very useful.  Usually, the only reason *not* to do an edit like that is if a full answer has already been posted, and changing the code would leave the answer not making sense.